# How do I make a .py plugin run on GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I am not sure if here is the right place to ask this question. If not, I would appreciate if anyone could point in the right direction.

I am trying to run a .py plugin in gimp, but it is not showing in the menu. I have a plugin that is .scm in the same folder that works, so I know that the folder is right, but all the .py files that are in the same folder do not show in GIMP.

I am running GIMP 2.10 in Linux.

Comment: Python plugins need to go in your GIMP plug-ins folder. This isn't the same as the scripts folder where .scm scripts go. To find where yours is located, in GIMP go into Edit > Preferences > Folders > Plug-ins.  There you should find the location of the folder. There's sometimes more than one listed. Also you can add a new folder if you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are more hoops to jump through on a linux system, but I suspect you may also need to make sure the plug-ins folder has read, write, and execute permissions.

Comment: In addition to @BillyKerr"s remarks, if you are on Linux, 1) the file must be marked executable and 2) you should have a Python support installed. Since Gimp wants Python 2.7 which is no longer supported, this is likely not the case if you installed Gimp from a .deb/rpm (check For `Filters > Python-fu > Console` (**not** `Filters > Script-fu > Console`)). There are alternate installs (flatpak/appimage) that come with their built-in Python support. Otherwise `SuperUser`, `Unix&Linux`, or `AskUbuntu` may be better places to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the folder. I found out that this command can show you the right folder:

Filters > Python-fu > Console and enter print gimp.directory.